# Permission denied to read datadog.yaml file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, datadog

I've installed the datadog app on my linux vm but i can't seem to read the datadog.yaml agent file.

[ Error reading /etc/datadog-agent/datadog.yaml: Permission denied ]

My linux box is hosted on GCP, do i need to configure permissions?

Comment: Help us by editing your question to provide more information: What Linux distribution and version? How did you install Datadog? Where are you seeing this error (what commands are producing it)? What is your goal? Please clarify the problem.

Comment: Provide more detailed information to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can open it by navigating to the directory it is in, and then typing

```
sudo nano datadog.yaml.
```

You need root permissions to view the file as far as I know.